# Segmentation fault(core dumped) C

Tags: c

I am trying to make an X[N][M] array with malloc, and I am having this error. Can anybody help me with that ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
  int N,M;  // N=megethos rows , M=megethos columns
  int **X;  // pinakas
  int size,i,j;


  printf("Give me the rows of the table: ");
  scanf("%d",&N);
  printf("Give me the columns: ");
  scanf("%d",&M);

  size = N*sizeof(int*);
  X = malloc(size);

  size = M * sizeof(int*);
  for(i=0; i<N;i++){
    X =malloc(size);
  }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      printf("Eisagwgh toy %d - %d stoixeioy: ",i+1,j+1);
      scanf("%d",&X[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      printf("%d",X[i][j]);
    }
  }
  free(X);
}
```

I have already try to change this line: 
`size = N*sizeof(int*);`
to this:  `size = N*sizeof(int);` but still same error appear.

Comment: You realize you overwrite `X` every time?

Comment: you need to malloc `X` ("array of pointers") once, and each `X[i]` ("array of ints") once... also free each `X[i]` and `X`

Comment: In for loop, using `X[i] = malloc(size); ` instead of `X = malloc(size);` and using `size = M * sizeof(int);` instead of `size = M * sizeof(int*);` (using `M *  sizeof(int*)` will waste the memory in this case)

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much guys :) I know it was a silly question. So at the end I should free the X[i] with a for loop right ?

Comment: Yup, you can free `X[i]` before `free(X)` if you dont still use them.

Comment: @Hitokiri You are awesome !! <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the below code, I just made a very small change in your code, must see the comment.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
  int N,M;  // N=megethos rows , M=megethos columns
  int **X;  // pinakas
  int size,i,j;


  printf("Give me the rows of the table: ");
  scanf("%d",&N);
  printf("Give me the columns: ");
  scanf("%d",&M);

  size = N*sizeof(int*);
  X = malloc(size);

  size = M * sizeof(int*);
  for(i=0; i<N;i++){
      //Here it intialize each row with size
    X[i] =malloc(size);
  }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      printf("Eisagwgh toy %d - %d stoixeioy: ",i+1,j+1);
      scanf("%d",&X[i][j]);
    }
  }

  for(i=0;i<N;i++){
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<M;j++){
      printf("%d",X[i][j]);
    }
  }
  free(X);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this way of allocating memory:

```
    X = malloc(N * sizeof(int*));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        X[i] = (int*)malloc(M * sizeof(int));
```

instead of this wrong allocating:

```
  size = N*sizeof(int*);
  X = malloc(size);

  size = M * sizeof(int*);
  for(i=0; i<N;i++){
    X =malloc(size);
  }
```